# Can I eat mice? If so, how to cook them?

Tags: food, foraging

We live on a farm in the countryside. Our cat often brings us his catch.

I was wondering whether I can eat those rodents (just out of curiosity and to hone survival skills). How shall I cook them? And there's one thing that concerns me: what if a rodent is poisoned by a rat poison? Would it hurt me or would heat treatment destroy the poision?

Comment: If there is rodent poison in your area it might cost you your cat. One factory I have worked used to have a factory cat, till they had more mice than the cat could handle and used poisoned bait. The cat died as the mice did/would have.

Comment: @Willeke The cat is outgoing, can't control it... there's no AREA poison but some local people might use poison. Once our cat came home with horrible diarrhea and we took him to the vet. The cat feels good. The mice are dead :)

Comment: Eating rodents is vegan???

Comment: @WeatherVane 100% VEGAN, 100% ECO, 100% MULTICULTURAL [and 100% sarcasm]

Comment: @WeatherVane The cat kills the mice/gerbil anyway. I can "steal" his catch from him and cook it, just to try it, just to know whether I can eat rodents in a survival situation. As a side note... I would expect CONSTRUCTIVE answers on StackExchange.

Comment: @Alexander I don't get it?

Comment: Mice are in the ballpark of 20g each. Assuming the similar yield as other animals animals (beef is under 50%, pork is above 50%), that's maybe 10 grams of meat per mouse on the outside. That wouldn't help you much.

Comment: @njzk2 Yeah I understand. But: 1. I just want to try it, for the sake of trying :) 2. Given a good enough mouse trap catching enough mice........ 10g times XXX mice ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eating mice is no different to any other mammal - skin it, gut it, cook it. I've never eaten one, but I suspect that the flavour would vary a bit depending on what they had been eating and the sex of the animal.

Male mice produce large amounts of some proteins known as [major urinary proteins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_urinary_proteins) (MUPs), that are the basis of the scent trails and territory markings they lay down. Females produce less of the MUPs, but I think mice in general will taste somewhat like the smell.

Romans ate [dormice with a spiced honey](https://www.romanobritain.org/2-arl_food/arl_roman_recipes-dormouse.php) as a delicacy (recipe in the website). [Dormice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormouse) are a bit different to the common mouse, being larger, and from a different family in the same order, but I don't know about their scent or flavour. Apparently still eaten in parts of Eastern Europe. Rats are also eaten in parts of the world, so I suspect that mice will be fine too.

Comment: +1, but feel compelled to add that Farley Mowat recommends eating the whole mouse, as wolves do.  He gives a recipe for whole mouse in cream sauce in his book Never Cry Wolf.  However, there seems to be a lot of fiction in this book, about the mouse-wolf connection, laccording to many reviewers.

Comment: Really sad that the dromouse-in-spiced-honey recipe is no longer available... :)